# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Spellcheck failed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get CheckSpelling to tell me if a word document has spell checked on or not, however it returns that spellcheck has failed on every word even if they're correct regardless of what I do. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Here is my code:

```
var allwords = aDoc.Range(aDoc.Content.Start, aDoc.Content.End).Text.Split(' '); 
                    foreach (var writtenword in allwords){ 
                        if (! wordApp.CheckSpelling(writtenword))
                        {
                        wordApp.GetSpellingSuggestions(writtenword); 
                                }
                    }
                    wordApp = new Word.Application();
                    var docpath = "C:\\Users\\netha\\Documents\\FSharpTest\\FTEST\\ftestdoc3.docx";
                    wordApp.Documents.Add(docpath);
                    aDoc = wordApp.Documents[1];
                    wordApp.CheckSpelling(aDoc.Range(aDoc.Content.Start, aDoc.Content.End).Text);
                    foreach(var writtenword in aDoc.Range(aDoc.Content.Start, aDoc.Content.End).Text.Split(' ') ) {
                        if (!wordApp.CheckSpelling(
                                writtenword,
                                ref CustomDictionary,
                                ref IgnoreUppercase,
                                ref MainDictionary,
                                ref CustomDictionary2,
                                ref CustomDictionary3,
                                ref CustomDictionary4,
                                ref CustomDictionary5,
                                ref CustomDictionary6,
                                ref CustomDictionary7,
                                ref CustomDictionary8,
                                ref CustomDictionary9,
                                ref CustomDictionary10)) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Spellcheck failed on " + writtenword);
                        wordApp.GetSpellingSuggestions(
                            writtenword,
                            ref CustomDictionary,
                            ref IgnoreUppercase,
                            ref MainDictionary,
                            ref CustomDictionary2,
                            ref CustomDictionary3,
                            ref CustomDictionary4,
                            ref CustomDictionary5,
                            ref CustomDictionary6,
                            ref CustomDictionary7,
                            ref CustomDictionary8,
                            ref CustomDictionary9,
                            ref CustomDictionary10); }
                    }

                    allwords = aDoc.Range(aDoc.Content.Start, aDoc.Content.End).Text.Split(' '); 
                    foreach (var writtenword in allwords)
                { 
                    if (!wordApp.CheckSpelling(writtenword)) {
                        wordApp.GetSpellingSuggestions(writtenword);

                } 
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code retrieves the words that contain spelling errors from the document. If you are getting unexpected results, it probably means that the proofing language isn't the one you seek.

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

try
{
    Document doc = app.Documents.Open(pathToFile);

    foreach (var word in doc.Words.Cast<Range>())
    {
        if (word.SpellingErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    //Use Try/Catch to avoid persisting Word processes in the event of an exception
}
finally
{
    app.Quit();
}
```